# Comparing 2 objects, wrong equals() and hashcode?

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

can somebody tell me why it returns "not equal"? Im searching for this for a long time and nothing... I think there is problem with my hashcode or/and equals method.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Student s1 = new Student();
        s1.setFirstName("Kamil");
        s1.setLastName("Witam");
        s1.setMark(3.0);
        s1.setAge(12);

        Student s2 = new Student();
        s2.setFirstName("Kamil");
        s2.setLastName("Witam");
        s2.setMark(3.0);
        s2.setAge(12);

        if( s1.equals(s2)){
            System.out.println("równe");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("sraka");
        }
    }
}
```

And my hashCode:

```
public int hashCode()
{
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;

    result = prime * result + age;
    result = prime * result + ( ( firstName == null ) ? 0 : firstName.hashCode() );
    result = prime * result + ( ( lastName == null ) ? 0 : lastName.hashCode() );

    long temp;
    temp = Double.doubleToLongBits( mark );
    result = prime * result + (int) ( temp ^ ( temp >>> 32 ) );

    return result;
}
```

And equals:

```
public boolean equals( Object obj )
{
    if ( this == obj )
        return true;

    if ( obj == null )
        return false;

    if ( getClass() != obj.getClass() )
        return false;

    Student other = (Student) obj;

    if ( age != other.age )
        return false;

    if ( firstName == null )
    {
        if ( other.firstName != null )
            return false;
    }
    else 
        if ( !firstName.equals( other.firstName ) )
            return false;

    if ( lastName == null )
    {
        if ( other.lastName != null )
            return false;
    }
    else 
        if ( !lastName.equals( other.lastName ) )
            return false;

    if ( mark != other.mark )
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Can somebody explain it to me :/? Thanks

Comment: A great place to learn using a debugger. What happens when you do this?

Comment: I see different ID for both Mark (doubles). Why is it so?

Comment: @KCrookedHand what do you mean by different ID for both mark? your code is working fine, see a live demo - https://ideone.com/wavsvC.

Comment: Ahhhh, I didn't see that it is a double. Comparing doubles is a tricky business, which you're finding out since digital computers don't hold exact representation of double values. Look this up and use other tests for "close enough"

Comment: More important: If this were my project, I wouldn't include marks in the equals and hashCode calculation. Only invariant fields such as name and date of birth should be used.

Comment: Is Student -> mark declared as a "Double" or "double"? if it is Double, then you want to compare by `!mark.equals(other.mark)`.

Comment: It is primitive double and unfortunately it have to be primitive :/ How should I properly compare it?

Comment: You should test for equality and calculate hashCode only with those fields that don't change, that define what a Student is. Typically for a Student class this could include name, some type of student id, and date of birth (better than age which *does* change). No fields that change with time should be used.